# Encadenado de operadores '<' '<=' '>' '>=' en Python para comprobar que un número está entre otros dos

Tags: python, python-3.x, operador

Tengo un problema, y es que cuando escribo un if y quiero hacer una comparación de números, por ejemplo: **Si 6 es mayor a 0 y si este es menor a 10 entonces se cumple el if**

Esto yo lo escribiría de la siguiente forma:

```
if 0 < 6 and 6 < 10:
    True
else:
    False
```

Básicamente mi duda es que se me hace muy innecesario repetir-lo dos veces el 6
habría alguna manera de refactorizar esto: `if 0 < 6 and 6 < 10:`

para así hacer-lo más corto?

Gracias de Antemano!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No lo sabía, pero parece que sí, se pueden encadenar operadores de comparación, haciéndolo más corto:

```
if 0 < 6 < 10:
```

Referencias:

- https://docs.python.org/es/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chaining-comparison-operators-python/

Comment: oh okei, Muchas Gracias por la solución y por las referencias donde hay las explicaciones!!

Comment: @Rock no le des las gracias, marca la respuesta como aceptada. Es el mejor agradecimiento y además ayudará a otros con la misma duda a saber que esto es correcto.

Comment: Es que le di como aceptada, pero me salto un mensaje que tenía que esperar 3 minutos de no sé que, se me olvido a volver a dar-le, pero ya le di como aceptada,

Comment: lo tendre en cuenta por la proxima :)